# Count many columns have the same value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot, sql-server-2017

How do I write an SQL query to return count the similar values for each column in one row?

**I have this:**

| emp_no | d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | d5 | d6 | d7 | d8 | d9 | d10 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1002 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 26 | 26 | 4 | 4 | 53 | 53 | 53 | 2021-03-31 |
| 1003 | 4 | 4 | 4 | 26 | 26 | 2 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 2021-03-31 |
| 1002 | 2 | 2 | 2 | 26 | 26 | 4 | 4 | 26 | 26 | 26 | 2021-04-30 |

**I want the result like this:**

| emp_no | 2 | 4 | 26 | 51 | 53 | date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1002 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 2021-03-31 |
| 1003 | 1 | 3 | 6 | 0 | 0 | 2021-03-31 |
| 1002 | 3 | 2 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 2021-04-30 |

I try `UNPIVOT` data, but how I can pivot this?

Do I create a view with unpivot data and after that re-pivot the aggregated data?

```
SELECT EMP_NO, TS_MTH_YR, TSS_D
FROM (
    SELECT EMP_NO, TS_MTH_YR, [D1], [D2], [D3], [D4], [D5], [D6], [D7], [D8], [D9], [D10]
    FROM TSS_MONTHLY_TS
) AS TSS
UNPIVOT (
    TSS_D FOR TSS_DAYS IN ([D1], [D2], [D3], [D4], [D5], [D6], [D7], [D8], [D9], [D10])
) AS TS
```

Comment: You'll effectively need to unpivot your data, and then re-pivot the aggregated data. What have you tried so far? Why didn't it work?

Comment: @Larnu How I do that?

Comment: whihc version of sql server are you using ?  `select @@version`

Comment: *"How I do that?"* Show your attempts? WIth the [edit] feature @AlQaqaaBenghuzi .

Comment: @eshirvana Microsoft SQL Server 2017 (RTM) - 14.0.1000.169 (X64)

Comment: Any reason you haven't applied any updates in the last 4 years, @AlQaqaaBenghuzi ..?

Comment: With SQL queries you select before-known columns. Do you know these columns? Do you know it will always be the columns 2, 4, 26, 51, and 53 you want to select? Or can there be other values in the future? If so, you need a dynamic approach. The easiest may be to simply `select *` and then have your app read row by row, column by column and build the grid in that process.

Comment: @Larnu I did unpivot my data and edit my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, you'll need to both unpivot and then repivot your data here. One method would therefore be the below:

```sql
WITH YourTable AS(
    SELECT emp_no ,d1 ,d2 ,d3 ,d4 ,d5 ,d6 ,d7 ,d8 ,d9 ,d10 , CONVERT(date,date) AS date --That's not confusing
    FROM (VALUES(1002,2,2,2,26,26,4,4 ,53 ,53 ,53 ,'2021-03-31'),
                (1003,4,4,4,26,26,2,26, 26, 26, 26,'    2021-03-31'),
                (1002,2,2,2,26,26,4,4 ,26 ,26 ,26 ,'2021-04-30'))V(emp_no ,d1 ,d2 ,d3 ,d4 ,d5 ,d6 ,d7 ,d8 ,d9 ,d10 ,date))
SELECT YT.emp_no,
       COUNT(CASE V.Val WHEN 2 THEN 1 END) AS [2],
       COUNT(CASE V.Val WHEN 4 THEN 1 END) AS [4],
       COUNT(CASE V.Val WHEN 26 THEN 1 END) AS [26],
       COUNT(CASE V.Val WHEN 51 THEN 1 END) AS [51],
       COUNT(CASE V.Val WHEN 53 THEN 1 END) AS [53],
       YT.[date]
FROM YourTable YT
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES('d1',YT.d1),
                        ('d2',YT.d2),
                        ('d3',YT.d3),
                        ('d4',YT.d4),
                        ('d5',YT.d5),
                        ('d6',YT.d6),
                        ('d7',YT.d7),
                        ('d8',YT.d8),
                        ('d9',YT.d9),
                        ('d10',YT.d10))V(Col,Val)
GROUP BY YT.emp_no,
         YT.[date];
```